# Which collection - each operation's spliterator is iterating over?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, spliterator

I'm trying to understand what exactly each operation's spliterator is iterating over. Please correct me if I'm wrong: (I'm most likely wrong)

1. Each stream have `.spliterator()` method.
2. Each intermediate operation can change the spliterator characteristics.

**My questions:**

1. Does each intermediate operation uses and changes characteristicts in the same spliterator - the "source spliterator"?
2. If we are using `filter` operation then some elements can be ommited. From which collection exactly those elements are ommited?

Comment: you are talking about parallel processing here, right? spliterators will be created from the *source* of the Stream - the `List` and `Set`, etc; not for intermediate operations. There would be many spliterators created from a single source that will partition it (each getting a chuck of the data), so that *the entire* stream pipeline is applied to that chunk. What you are probably talking is a `Sink`, that will indeed capture values for `stateful` operations, but not for the stateless ones as far as I understood looking at the code a while ago

Comment: I have rephrased the question after your comment. Also I did not mention parallel proccesing because I thought it should have the same answer +-.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes - it is the same spliterator. Only a single spliterator is created from the source of the `Stream` (there could be many Spliterators in case of parallel processing).
2. It is the result Collection (the one from the terminal operation - which might not be a collection at all - `sum`, `count`, etc) that the elements are omitted from.